# Postgresql gist index is not hit

Tags: postgresql

I am using `PostgreSQL` version 9.3.

I just learned that the normal `b-tree` indexes can not be used for like queries with 'x%x%x' wildcards and I find `gist` and `gin` indexes to make my wildcard like queries hit an index.

So I decided to use those indexes and I added `btree-gist` extension by using the command in PostgreSQL;

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
```

After that I added my gist index to my table and it was like ;

```
CREATE INDEX ix_bras_interface_name ON bras_interface USING GIST (name);
```

After I added this, I could see it is really added;

```
   table_name   |                index_name                 |    column_name
----------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------
 bras_interface | bras_interface_context_id                 | context_id
 bras_interface | bras_interface_domain_id                  | domain_id
 bras_interface | bras_interface_managed_object_id          | managed_object_id
 bras_interface | bras_interface_name_59ec675d0b9537ac_uniq | context_id
 bras_interface | bras_interface_name_59ec675d0b9537ac_uniq | name
 bras_interface | bras_interface_name_idx                   | name
 bras_interface | bras_interface_pkey                       | id
 bras_interface | bras_interface_task_id                    | task_id
 **bras_interface | ix_bras_interface_name                    | name**
(9 rows)
```

But, my simple query is still not hit the index. Here is my simple query and its analyser result;

```
my_user=# explain ANALYZE select * from bras_interface where name like '%my_text%';
                                                 QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on bras_interface  (cost=0.00..764.95 rows=1 width=1420) (actual time=5.589..5.589 rows=0 loops=1)
   Filter: ((name)::text ~~ '%my_text%'::text)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 27596
 Total runtime: 5.613 ms
(4 rows)
```

And I see it is not hitting the index. I followed the tutorials about that and couldn't see the solution, even the problem. 
What am I missing about gist indexing?

Comment: You need the module `pg_trgm` in order to use an index for `'%my_text%'`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html

Comment: I did'nt understand exactly. In the documentation that you gave, it says; _Beginning in PostgreSQL 9.1, these index types also support index searches for LIKE and ILIKE_. What exaclty do you mean whlie saying 'need module pg_term in order to use an index'. Isn't using pg_term another index usage?

Comment: You need to install that extension, otherwise the index won't be used. See here http://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/

Answer (score 0):

Like a_horse_with_no_name has said, you've picked the wrong extension.

The [btree_gist](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html) extension lets you use an index to back a "distance" operator. It also lets you have a gist index spanning multiple columns where one might be e.g. a tsearch vector and another a simple int.

The [pg_trgm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) extension is the one that does match-anywhere-in-string indexing. Be aware that it's quite an expensive index though.